# Android LocationServices respond only one time

Tags: java, android, location, google-location-services, fusedlocationproviderclient

I want to implement a logger, which stores the location of the client after a certain time or when the position is changed. When i am starting the logger, it serves the location only one time. When i am changing the position of the client, nothing happens.
The permissions ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are granted and i am using an emulator with play store installed.

Here is my code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Granularity;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Priority;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCanceledListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import de.remi.locker.database.entities.Trip;
import de.remi.locker.util.MapsHelper;
import de.remi.locker.util.PermissionHelper;

public class AndroidLogger implements AutoLogger.ILoggerClient {
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidLogger";
    private final FragmentActivity activity;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    private LocationCallback callBack;

    public AndroidLogger(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
        callBack = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                locationResult.getLocations().forEach(location -> handleLocation(location));
            }
        };
    }

    private void handleLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleLocation: " + location);
    }

    private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest.Builder builder = new LocationRequest.Builder(10000);
        builder.setMinUpdateDistanceMeters(50);
        builder.setDurationMillis(60 * 1000);
        builder.setGranularity(Granularity.GRANULARITY_FINE);
        builder.setWaitForAccurateLocation(false);
        builder.setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void startLogging(Trip trip) {
        if (!PermissionHelper.hasPermissions(activity.getApplicationContext(), MapsHelper.OSM_PERMISSIONS))
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("permissions missing ");

        client.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), callBack, Looper.myLooper()).addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCanceled() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCanceled: ");
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e);
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void stopLogging() {
        client.removeLocationUpdates(callBack);
    }
```

In my understanding every 60 seconds or after a position change of minimum 50 meters a new position log should be performed.
I used several emulators, from API 30 - 33, changed the CallBack to a listener, nothing changed. Also i changed several parameters of the LocationRequest, without any change

Hope anybody has a helping hint

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: actually i found the solution: i had to add FOREGROUND_SERVICE as permission to the manifest and all works fine